# org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: account)

Tags: java, sqlite, intellij-idea

i know this question maybe have repeated several times, but i couldn't find a real answer to this problem
" so i want to connect sqlite database to Java application , I am using Intellij and using sqlite-jdbc-3.34.0 as external library
I am trying to read from the database "account" using select.
and got this error in different placses

```
  org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: account)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:1012)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:1024)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.throwex(DB.java:989)
    at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.prepare_utf8(Native Method)
    at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.prepare(NativeDB.java:134)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.prepare(DB.java:257)
    at org.sqlite.core.CorePreparedStatement.<init>(CorePreparedStatement.java:45)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3PreparedStatement.<init>(JDBC3PreparedStatement.java:30)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4PreparedStatement.<init>(JDBC4PreparedStatement.java:25)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4Connection.prepareStatement(JDBC4Connection.java:35)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.prepareStatement(JDBC3Connection.java:241)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.prepareStatement(JDBC3Connection.java:205)
    at Test.main(Test.java:35)
```

I tried a lot of methods to solve it but couldn't, If you plz can help me.

```
import org.sqlite.SQLiteConfig;
import org.sqlite.SQLiteDataSource;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC"); 
            SQLiteConfig config = new SQLiteConfig();
            config.setPragma(SQLiteConfig.Pragma.FOREIGN_KEYS, "on");

            SQLiteDataSource dataSource = new SQLiteDataSource(config); 

dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\SQLDATABASES\\sampleDatabases\\bankDB");
            Connection dbConn = dataSource.getConnection();
      

         
            String queryString = "SELECT * FROM account ";
            PreparedStatement statement = dbConn.prepareStatement(queryString);
      
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
            
            //print the header line
            System.out.println("account_no, account_id, balance");
            System.out.println("--------------------------------");
            //check if result has any rows
            while (result.next()) {
               
                String accountNo = result.getString("account_no"); 
                System.out.print(accountNo + ", ");

                int accountID = result.getInt("account_id");
                System.out.print(accountID + ", ");

                int balance = result.getInt("balance");
                System.out.println(balance);
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


    }
}
```

I tried to put the .db3 file inside the src folder and tried to remove .idea folder, also Invalidate caches / restart , or updated Intellij and nothing of these worked !.

Comment: make sure in your database having a 'Account' table?

Comment: Yes it is there and confirmed that with CMD and sqlitestudio

Answer (score 0):

copy your database file to your project folder. sometimes sqlite database file being in my `src` folder.  move it from  `src` folder to my project folder,this way can be solve the error

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your sqlite database path is wrong.